# What is armature parent type in object relations

Tags: armature, parent

[image]

I'm very familiar with the Object and Bone types when I parent objects. But I'm not sure about the Armature type. In fact, even if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, Armature Deform manipulation parent the mesh to armature, Parent Type is Object. What is the difference between Armature type and Object type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in `blender/object_relations.c` at line 660:

```c
/* Operator Property */
EnumPropertyItem prop_make_parent_types[] = {
    {PAR_OBJECT, "OBJECT", 0, "Object", ""},
    {PAR_ARMATURE, "ARMATURE", 0, "Armature Deform", ""},
    {PAR_ARMATURE_NAME, "ARMATURE_NAME", 0, "   With Empty Groups", ""},
    {PAR_ARMATURE_AUTO, "ARMATURE_AUTO", 0, "   With Automatic Weights", ""},
    {PAR_ARMATURE_ENVELOPE, "ARMATURE_ENVELOPE", 0, "   With Envelope Weights", ""},
    {PAR_BONE, "BONE", 0, "Bone", ""},
    {PAR_BONE_RELATIVE, "BONE_RELATIVE", 0, "Bone Relative", ""},
    {PAR_CURVE, "CURVE", 0, "Curve Deform", ""},
    {PAR_FOLLOW, "FOLLOW", 0, "Follow Path", ""},
    {PAR_PATH_CONST, "PATH_CONST", 0, "Path Constraint", ""},
    {PAR_LATTICE, "LATTICE", 0, "Lattice Deform", ""},
    {PAR_VERTEX, "VERTEX", 0, "Vertex", ""},
    {PAR_VERTEX_TRI, "VERTEX_TRI", 0, "Vertex (Triangle)", ""},
    {0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL},
};
```

It is an alias for *Armature Deform*.  If you look through that file you'll find it gets used as a way of covering both armatures that use weights and armatures that use envelops; but the only place it currently seems to matter is in grease pencil.